# Exporting data out of Google AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

Currently, I store my data on google-drive tables. When I export the data to spreadsheets, the relationship between models are lost. For example, I have a farm object and contacts tied to that farm object.

When I export the data of farms and contacts from my deployment, google gives me a spreadsheet with two sheets (farms, contacts). Each of them contains the data but the relationship of farms and contacts tie to each other is not shown or listed.

Is it not possible to show the relationship? Should I use the google cloud SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was addressed with one of the latest App Maker releases:

> **November 9, 2017**
>
> You can now import and export all app data and relations.

You can read full release note by pointing your browser to this link:
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/release-notes#import_and_export_relations

Documentation related to import and export functionality can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export