# Export filtered data from table widget Google AppMaker to a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-app-maker

Does anyone know how we can **export filtered data** from Google App Maker **table widget**.

My table from the data source (no filter):
[image: that show everything]

After applying some filter
[image: filtered].

I manage to export everything to Google Spreadsheet [(see this SO answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49051555/9426876), but I am stuck on exporting only the data after applying some filter. Really appreciate if anyone can share the solution. Thanks!

Comment: You tagged this as Apps Script.. I don't see any code that you have tried. What have you tried?

Comment: I manage to export all data from datasource of AppMaker using the Client Script, but now I just want to export filtered data from table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [AMU Library](https://script.google.com/d/148C-svFP_-50XseKiXFScVM8DgIozY_FALFlzkEtu2fI7l0_yt0FvbOh/edit?usp=sharing) can do this in one command in a button onClick. 
The button just needs to be on the same datasource as the table.

Simply:

```
AMU.export.toSpreadsheet = function(widget, Your_modelName);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for [filters](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#Query). It should work if you modify script from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49042255) to something similar to this:

```javascript
// Server script
function dataExport(filter1, filter2, ...) {
  // TODO: Check permissions.
  ...
  var query = app.models.MyModel.newQuery();

  // TODO: Apply user/roles specific filters for
  // security reasons.
  query.filters.Field1._equals = filter1;
  query.filters.Field2._greaterThan = filter2;
  ...
  var filteredRecords = query.run();

  filteredRecords.forEach(function(record) {
    ...
  });
  ...
```