# How to export table from google app maker using AMU code

Tags: google-app-maker

I have been trying to export a table to google app maker to sheets using the AMU code and the comment from this previous question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481920/10956377

However, I cannot get it to work whatever I try.

Does anybody have any experience with this. My coding is basic at best but I can vaguely understand other people's.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I presume you've done this but first install the [AMU client and server libraries](https://script.google.com/d/148C-svFP_-50XseKiXFScVM8DgIozY_FALFlzkEtu2fI7l0_yt0FvbOh/edit?usp=sharing). Then add this code to your button's onClick event:

```
AMU.export.toSpreadsheet(widget, 'modelName');
```

Where **modelName** is the name of the data model you wish to export to the spreadsheet.